# How to set the left space(left of line numbers) wilder in vim/neovim?

Tags: neovim

How do I make this space wider?
When my code is not all right, informations will show up here.
Then the width changes all the time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `:help 'signcolumn'` would be a good start.

Answer (score 5):

add this in init.lua seems help

```lua
vim.wo.signcolumn = "yes"
```

Comment: You saved my eyes and concentration. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

```
vim.o.signcolumn = 'auto' -- this is what you seem to be using.
vim.o.signcolumn = 3 -- will use 3 columns. 
vim.o.signcolumn = 'number' -- will display signs in the number column.
```

Read the documentation. `:h signcolumn`